# How to exclude an object from Freestyle render?

Tags: objects, freestyle

The question is how can I exclude an object from the freestyle render?

What I need to do is create a Clay render with the wire only on the airplane.

My scene is simple I only have two objects the "Toy Plane" and the "floor".
For the Clay render I only override the materials to a simple clay material and done.
[image: Viewport]
[image: SimpleClay]

But this happens when I use freestyle. How can I tell freestyle to ignore the "Floor"?

[image: render with freestyle]

Comment: I never used freestyle, but you talk about the wireframe modifier but you dont tell us why you dont use this solution. This tutorial could help you if this kind of render fits your needs: [How to Render a Wireframe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAaToapgBxQ)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

So you want freestyle on the plane but not the plane :)

This is very easy to do. Add the plane to an object group. Select it and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>.

Now in the Scene tab of the Properties panel scroll down to the "Freestyle Line Set" section, and add *Group* to the *"Selection By:"* setting. (outlined in red in the image below)
[image: freestyle settings]

Set the group you made earlier as the "Group" (the group field will be on the bottom).
Now depending on which plane you grouped, click the "Inclusive" box if you grouped your airplane; because you want to only include objects in the group in this freestyle lines. Conversely  if you grouped the ground plane click the "Exclusive" box, to exclude the ground plane from freestyle.

Comment: Thank you David this works. So you cannot exclude objects this is only possible using groups and a group can have multiple objects.

Comment: yes, kind of. This is the simplest way to do it, but you could use different render layers, or using "Face Marks". But there is no way to just say "only render lines on this object" or exclude this object. Closest thing is a group with one object in it.

Comment: in Blender 2.9+ this is now called "Collections" instead of "Groups"

Answer (score 7):

For Blender 2.82 in the Outliner add a new collection by right-clicking on an existing collection and selecting *New*).

Name it, if you want, to "No Freestyle" and drag the object into it.

Now go into *View Layer Properties* and under *Freestyle Line Set* check *Selection By: Collection*. Now at the bottom choose the collection you created and check the *Exclusive* box.

In the render all objects in that collection should be without freestyle edges.

Comment: Note that this has to be done for **each** style defined within the "Freestyle Line Set" panel

Answer (score 2):

Addding to the previous answer, if you want to avoid using Groups, under *Edge Types* uncheck all checkboxes except *Edge Mark*. Then to freestyle a particular object, go to it's Edit mode, select all edges. Then *Mesh -> Edges -> Mark Freestyle edges*

This would apply freestyle only on edges that are marked. Worked for me... :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Blender 3.6:

1. Create a new collection for all objects you want to exclude from applying Freestyle. Example: "Collection NO FS"
2. Move all objects you want to exclude to the new collection.
3. Go to "View Layer" Tab and locate "Freestyle Line Set"
4. Enable Collection, select the collection you created.
5. Set Negation to Exclusion.

[image]